# presence_of_element_located by class

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using python and selenium and when I try to locate an error generated by the javascript (failed login message)

but since it takes a few moments I need to wait for presence by class.

but this By.Class doesn't exist and I only have class in my login.

```
try_login(driver,'admin99','123')
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"alert"))
)
x = driver.find_element_by_id('alert')
```

Comment: Can you provide the url?

Comment: no, it's localhost. basically it's just a div with the error and it has a class only and text in the innerhtml. **that div is generated by the javascript**

Comment: First guess would be your css selector `alert` is wrong. Second, why do you use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` but then `find_element_by_id` below? Could you use `By.ID` instead of `By.CSS_SELECTOR`?

Comment: it's a typo. it should be `find_element_by_class`

Comment: Ok, then what is the reason you use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` instead of `By.CLASS_NAME`?

Comment: Pretty much contradictory statements `generated by the javascript` & `wait for presence by class`

Answer (score 0):

Putting it straight if the error is generated by **Javascript** (failed login message) then only its an **Alert** and should be handled through `expected_conditions` clause set to `alert_is_present` as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present).accept()
#or
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present).dismiss()
```